# jqCycle and tab switching bugs

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I used jqCycle ([Malsup's excellent version](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)) for an auto-rotating slideshow and have it successfully working in Firefox, IE9, and Chrome, however often it will not move if I switch between tabs in Chrome/webkit.  I have no JS errors.  Could anyone point out what could be the motive for the slideshow just to stop sliding on its own?  When I click to get the images moving, it starts sliding again on its own...

EDIT: I noticed it usually affects pages with two slideshows, if that might help?  Again, no JS problems and code is all clean.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same weird issue. I shifted from jQuery 1.6.2 to 1.5.2 (they are using 1.5.2 on http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/browser.html). It seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks Tavs! Any other mention anywhere of why that is?